# How to name a the other party of financial transaction (both recipient and sender)?

Tags: finance

I am translating a balance sheet and it has a column name of the recipient or a sender of the money. Is there a word that designates "the other party in a transaction"?

Comment: [*Counterparty*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/counterparty)

Comment: If that was an answer, I'd upvote it.